# Loop until grep does not find the text in a file

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I have a file named `file.txt`. The content of the file is as follows

```
sunday
monday
tuesday
```

I wrote the below script and it loops just fine if the `grep` cannot find the pattern that was mentioned

```
until cat file.txt | grep -E "fdgfg" -C 9999; do sleep 1 | echo "working..."; done
```

But my requirement is that the above script should loop until the text mentioned in the `grep` pattern disappears in the  `file.txt`

I tried to use the `L` flag with grep. But it didn't work.

```
until cat file.txt | grep -EL "sunday" -C 9999; do sleep 1 | echo "working..."; done
```

Answer (score 0):

This works (in bash, at least):

```
until ! grep -E "fdgdg" -C 9999 /tmp/file.txt; do sleep 1; echo "working..."; done
```